# Regular Expressions Dependant on Previous Matchings

Tags: python, regex

For example, how could we recognize a string of the following format with a single RE:

```
LenOfStr:Str
```

An example string in this format is:

```
5:5:str
```

The string we're looking for is "5:str".

In python, maybe something like the following (this isn't working):

```
r'(?P<len>\d+):(?P<str>.{int((?P=len))})'
```

In general, is there a way to change the previously matched groups before using them or I just asked yet another question not meant for RE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, what you're describing is outside the bounds of regular expressions.  Regular expressions only deal with actual character data.  This provides some limited ability to make matches dependent on context (e.g., `(.)\1` to match the same character twice), but you can't apply arbitrary functions to pieces of an in-progress match and use the results later in the same match.

You could do something like search for text matching the regex `(\d+):\w+`, and then postprocess the results to check if the string length is equal to the int value of the first part of the match.  But you can't do that as part of the matching process itself.

Comment: Thanks for the input, looks like it is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Well this *can* be done with a regex (if I understand the question):

```
>>> s='5:5:str and some more characters...'
>>> m=re.search(r'^(\d+):(.*)$',s)
>>> m.group(2)[0:int(m.group(1))]
'5:str'
```

It just cannot be done by dynamically changing the previous match group.

You can make it *lool* like a single regex like so:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^(\d+):(.*)$',lambda m: m.group(2)[0:int(m.group(1))],s)
'5:str'
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you guys gave the same solution. @BrenBarn

Comment: Yeah, you guys gave the same solution. @BrenBarn But I think you are both on the point "regex" is not meant for the job. While your solution sure works, it does have to return you the entire input stream (if under re.S) while you're throwing most of them away. So you cannot keep processing it without rewinding. Anyways, thanks guys.